# Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:

Tags: angular, ionic2

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/cordova/BuildHelper;
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

How can I fixed that issue I can't able to build apk file for android.

Comment: Looks like you tagged this with angular instead of android.

Comment: not getting your mean? I am getting error
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1).
when run commend ionic cordova build android

Comment: I found the issue with ionic cordova plugin cordova-plugin-admob-free
when I type commend ionic cordova plugin rm --save cordova-plugin-admob-free   it is working for me